# How to do something after clicking on MessageBox button, but before this MessageBox closes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a list of "projects" with some informations in textBoxs for each project. The user can select a project then modify the informations and click on save button after that.

If I changes selected project without save the modifications, a Yes/No MessageBox appear:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
            "Do you want to save changes ?",
            "Title",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //Click Yes
}
else
{
    //Click No
}
```

I would to refresh all the project list (with my own Refresh() methode) after clicking on Yes/No button, but staying on the MessageBox until the refresh is done.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, MessageBox.Show is modal. This means that when you call this method the code doesn't return until you press the Yes/No buttons

Comment: Why do you want to stay on the MessageBox?

Comment: You will need to create your own form for such a feature.

Comment: Yes I know that the code "//Click Yes" or "//Click No" is execute only after clicking. But between clicking and this code, can I execute other code ?

Comment: To prevent user to do something else before Refresh().

Comment: @ThomasDeray well probably it would be useful if the MessageBox.Show has some kind of event to which you could link your own code, but this isn't the case and this famous post from C# master Eric Lippert explains a lot [How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a light bulb?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/)

Comment: Okok thanks to your answers ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in `MessageBox` class does not allow such complicated behaviour.

One way to do this is to create your own message box. Create a subclass of `Form`, add some labels and buttons. Expose some events like `YesClicked` and `NoClicked`.

In your main form, create an instance of your custom message box, subscribe to the events, and call `ShowDialog` on it.

After the refresh is done, you can call `Close` or `Dispose` on your custom message box to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom message box. I commented the code, let me know if you need clarification

```
public static class MessageBoxResult
{
    public static int dialogResult;  // <== i use this value to determine what button was pressed
}

// your custom message box form code
public partial class CustomMsgBox : Form
{
    public CustomMsgBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void show(string pos0, string pos1, string pos2, string message)  //<=== initializing the message box with the values from your main code
    {
        button1.Text = pos0;
        button2.Text = pos1;
        button3.Text = pos2;
        label1.Text = message;
    }


 // message box events to set the static field incase a button on the custom form was changed
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult.dialogResult = 0;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult.dialogResult = 1;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult.dialogResult = 2;
        this.Close();
    }
}


//usage
{
    MessageBoxResult.dialogResult = -1;   // <== setting the static field to -1 to mean nothing was pressed
    CustomMsgBox cMsgBox = new CustomMsgBox();
    cMsgBox.show("your message");
    cMsgBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change what happends, based on what button is clicked, with the `DialogResult`

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(@"Some body", @"Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, a message box cannot do this. It's not meant to do this. It's meant to just display a message... in a box :)

What you can always do is create your own window that looks like a message box and behaves like a message box, but actually does things when you click the buttons.